# Join Talbe to itself having count > 1

Tags: sql-server-2005, join, uniqueidentifier, unique-constraint

I have a `Personal` table with a `LastName` column and a `MaybeUniqueID`.
I want to put in output a table with a `LastName` column where the counter set on to the column `MaybeUniqueID` gives more than 1 row.

- I would like to do everything in one unique run, avoiding mid-step outputs.
- I prefere not using temporary table or table variables, otherwise I would like to use at most one table variable (not temporary tables), but I think this should not be necessary.
- I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2005.

I tried different scenarios with different SQL statements like `HAVING` or `GROUP BY`, but I failed to get the outcome I am looking for.
Please have a look at the following not-working summary test:

```
SELECT LastName
FROM   Personal
       JOIN
              (SELECT  MaybeUniqueID AS ID2,
                       COUNT(*)      AS CNT
              FROM     Personal
                       --WHERE CNT > 1
              GROUP BY MaybeUniqueID
              HAVING   cnt > 1
              ) AS MultiMaybeUniqueID
       ON     Personal.MaybeUniqueID = MultiMaybeUniqueID.ID2
```

Comment: Why does this not do what you expect?

Comment: I think (now after reading the answer below) that the problem was the alias `cnt`. I should have used `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`HAVING   cnt > 1` should be `HAVING   COUNT(*)  > 1`.

Column aliases can only be referenced in the `ORDER BY` clause not the `HAVING` clause.

Though you could also use

```
;WITH T AS
(
SELECT LastName,
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY MaybeUniqueID) AS Cnt
FROM Personal
)
SELECT LastName
FROM T 
WHERE Cnt > 1
```